# Why a equatable protocol needs to be defined outside the class?

Tags: swift, hashable

When i implement the Hashable protocol. a equatable protocol function is needed to be defined outside the class as follow. As follow.

```
func ==(lhs: Swap, rhs: Swap) -> Bool {
    return (lhs.cookieA == rhs.cookieA && lhs.cookieB == rhs.cookieB) ||
        (lhs.cookieB == rhs.cookieA && lhs.cookieA == rhs.cookieB)
}

class Swap: Printable,Hashable {
    var cookieA: Cookie
    var cookieB: Cookie

    init(cookieA: Cookie, cookieB: Cookie) {
        self.cookieA = cookieA
        self.cookieB = cookieB
    }
    var hashValue: Int {
    return cookieA.hashValue ^ cookieB.hashValue
    }

    var description: String {
    return "swap \(cookieA) with \(cookieB)"
    }
}
```

It is just a bit weird for me. In the above example func == should be belong to the class Swap. So why we need to declare the func == outside the class??

Comment: equatable is naturally a typeclass… and typeclass instances are defined outside of types. http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/using-typeclasses.html

Comment: [Here's a great explanation, along with a discussion how this may change in the future](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35246003/why-must-a-protocol-operator-be-implemented-as-a-global-function).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mainly because it's a **function** and not a **method**. Functions are independent on classes so it makes no sense to scope them inside class declarations.

The protocol could have been designed with methods, e.g. using a `obj1.isEqualTo(obj2)` method but a function is less sensitive to `nil` problems. If `obj1` were `nil`, the method would fail.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't read too much into it. I think it's just a simple design decision. Yes, in many languages operator overloads are methods on the left-hand-side operand and that's fine, but defining operators as functions probably gives you a bit more flexibility so they decided to make them all functions.

Answer (score 1):

The operator function is defined as a global function with a function name that matches the operator to be overloaded.
The function is defined globally, rather than as a method on the target class or structure, so that it can be used as an infix operator between existing instances of the target class or structure.

I have answered this question in detail in my blog post [here](https://lifewithios.wordpress.com/2016/05/17/swift-tidbits-1-equatable-implemented-outside-the-class/). Hope it helps.