# Removing a collection of custom types from a Swift Array

Tags: arrays, swift, indexing, indexof

I've created a Swift array that contains collections of two instances of a custom data type:

```
var myArray : [(MyDataType, MyDataType)]!
```

When I want to add items to this array, it's trivial to do so with the following code (where `firstVar` and `secondVar` are instances of `MyDataType`)

```
myArray.append((firstVar, secondVar))
```

What I'm currently struggling with is removing items from `myArray`. Using this code, I get an error of `Value of type '[(MyDataType, MyDataType)]' has no member 'indexOf'`:

```
    let indexOfA = myArray.indexOf((firstVar, secondVar))

    myArray.remove(at: indexOfA)
```

Honestly somewhat confused, so any help as to how to get the index of an item of `(MyDataType, MyDataType)` so that I can then remove it from `myArray` would be extremely helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your MyDataType conform to Equatable and use index(where:) method to find your tuple (which conforms also to Equatable):

**Swift 4.1**  Taking advantage of [proposal se-0185](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0185-synthesize-equatable-hashable.md)

```
struct MyDataType: Equatable {
    let id: Int
}
```

---

```
var array : [(MyDataType,MyDataType)] = []

let tuple = (MyDataType(id: 1), MyDataType(id: 2))
array.append(tuple)

if let index = array.index(where: { $0 == tuple }) {
    array.remove(at: index)
}
```